# Как правильно вызывать функции с другого файла

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Есть два файла, передаю `state` из `main.js` в `gameCreate.js` . Обращаюсь к функции через this, и получаю ошибку. Как правильно обращатся к функциям других файлов ?

```
main.js

function checkDown() {
    if (CAN_CLICK) {
        CAN_CLICK = false;
        last_pointer_position.x = game.input.activePointer.worldX;
        last_pointer_position.y = game.input.activePointer.worldY;

        setTimeout(function () {
            CAN_CLICK = true;
        }, 200)
    }


   };

game = new Phaser.Game(_GLOBAL.Width, _GLOBAL.Height, Phaser.CANVAS, 'game');

game.state.add('menu', gameCreate);
game.state.start('menu');
```

и

```
gameCreate.js

var gameCreate = {
    preload: function () {
    }

    create: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.game.input.onDown.add(self.checkDown, this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую использовать модули (import и export).
[Вот ссылка, объясняющая их работу](https://medium.com/web-standards/es-modules-cartoon-dive-71f42c1e851a)

Пример того, как это все используется:
`index.js`

```js
import some from './some';

console.log(some.avg(1,5,76,9,535));
console.log(some.max(1,5,76,9,535,14));
```

`some.js`

```js
function sum(...numbers) {
    return numbers.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
        return previousValue + currentValue;
    })
}
class SomeMath {
    avg(...numbers) {
        return sum(...numbers)/numbers.length;
    }
    max(...numbers){
        return Math.max(...numbers);
    }
}
export default new SomeMath;
```

Только тут передается класс, но с функциями аналогичная ситуация :)
Передача функции:
`main.js`

```js
function checkDown(){
    console.log("Check down");
}
export default checkDown();
```

`gameCreate.js`

```js
import checkdown from './main.js';
checkdown(); //output: "Check down"
```

P.S. Подключай главный js файл (в котором используются все модули) в html следующим образом `<script src="название_файла.js" type="module"></script>`